# `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for the file </path/to/folder>` when I attempt `open .`

Tags: macos, finder, bash

I suddenly came across this error when I attempted to do `open .` to open the current directory in Finder, a command that I use quite frequently:

```
ysim:~/Downloads$ open .
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for the file /Users/ysim/Downloads.
```

It persisted for a few minutes and went away by itself. I tried googling it but the only two hits I saw had to do with ImageMagick and Automator, neither of which I use. Does anyone know why it happens and how to prevent it?

Comment: Since i updated to yosemite ( osx 10.10 )  i get this always when opening more than 6 urls simultaneously

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That error means an Apple Event timed out.

```
error -1712 errAETimeout: the AppleEvent timed out
```

You can either open Activity Monitor and look to see if you notice an Application or process that states `Not responding` or hit <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd> then `force quit` any non-responding application.

It's possible the application or process was already open and by using `open .` it tried to launch it for whatever reason. Often it's an Automator or AppleScript that is waiting for user interaction and "times out" waiting.

Comment: Happened to me when trying to open a PowerPoint file. I had exited PowerPoint before, but not quite, it got stuck somehow. After "force quit"-ting PowerPoint, `open somefile.pptx` worked again.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was a reboot.  It was almost like I was using Windows